# Show contents of a md file in another in GitHub

Tags: github, markdown, documentation, github-flavored-markdown

I am working on writing some docs for an open-source project on GitHub. I want to do something like I have a MarkDown file called `section1.md` let's say it has some contents like(example purpose)-

```
Section 1 contents here
```

I have another Markdown file (in my case it is the `README.md` file itself) and I want it to show content like this-

The output I need:

#### Section 1

Section 1 contents here

The contents of the markdown file:

```
### Section 1
Some code to show contents of section1.md
```

How do I complete this to get the above shown output?